# Read file into string by separating words by tab

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code where it reads a file and sorts the words by the tabs in between the words.

**File Example**

```
Area Word Area Word Area 1111 Word
```

```java
public static void start() throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Create Empty address book
        AddressBook book = new AddressBook();
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = "contacts.txt";
        addContactfromFile(book,filename);
        System.out.println("Number of Contacts" +book.getNumberOfContacts());

        // Insert contacts FEATURE
        System.out.println("------------------------INSERTING CONTACT--------------------------------");
        int ans = 0;
        System.out.println("Would you like to insert a Contact? 1 or 2");
        ans = scnr.nextInt();
        scnr.nextLine();
        if(ans == 1){
            System.out.println("What is the First name");
            String f = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the Last name");
            String l = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the Number name");
            String n = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the Address name");
            String a = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the City name");
            String c = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the State name");
            String s = scnr.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the Zip Code name");
            int z = scnr.nextInt();
            book.insertContact(f,l,n,a,c,s,z);
            System.out.println("Contact has been added!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Contacts" +book.getNumberOfContacts());
        System.out.println("Now emptying the Address Book");
        book.emptyAddressBook();

        // search FEATURE
        System.out.println("------------------------SEARCHING CONTACT--------------------------------");
        addContactfromFile(book, "contacts.txt");
        checkSearch(book);
        System.out.println("Number of Contacts" +book.getNumberOfContacts());
        System.out.println("Now emptying the Address Book");
        book.emptyAddressBook();

        // delete Contact FEATURE
        System.out.println("------------------------DELETING CONTACT--------------------------------");
        addContactfromFile(book, "contacts.txt");
        checkDelete(book);
        System.out.println("Number of Contacts" +book.getNumberOfContacts());
        System.out.println("Now emptying the Address Book");
        book.emptyAddressBook();

        // Check if address book is empty FEATURE
        addContactfromFile(book, "contacts.txt");
        System.out.println("Is the Address Book Empty: "+book.isAddressBookEmpty());
        System.out.println(book.getNumberOfContacts());

    }

    public static void checkSearch(AddressBook book) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Who would like to look for?'First name'");
        String first = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Who would like to look for?'Last name'");
        String last = scnr.nextLine();
        try{
            Contact c = book.searchContact(first,last);
            System.out.println(c.getFirstName()+ " " + c.getAddress().getStreet());
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Contact isnt there");
        }
    }

    public static void checkDelete(AddressBook book) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Name");
        String first = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
        String last = scnr.nextLine();
        try{
            book.deleteContact(first,last);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Didnt work");
        }
    }

    public static void addContactfromFile(AddressBook book, String filename) throws NumberFormatException, FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String contactString = reader.nextLine();
            String[] contactElementStrings = contactString.split("\t");
            int zipcode = Integer.parseInt(contactElementStrings[5]);
            Address address = new Address(contactElementStrings[2],contactElementStrings[3],contactElementStrings[4],zipcode);
            Contact contact = new Contact(contactElementStrings[0],contactElementStrings[1],address,contactElementStrings[6]);
            book.insertContact2(contact);
        }
    }
```

The Error I receive from this is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Helper.addContactfromFile(Helper.java:106)
    at Helper.start(Helper.java:16)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:17)
```

Comment: Without looking too detailed I would say there might be a problem with your input data. With the given sample it should work. But maybe there is a line in your input data which doesn't have a zip code at position 6. I would recommend to catch `int zipcode = Integer.parseInt(contactElementStrings[5]);` and output the entire `contactString`. That should show you where the error is

Answer (score 1):

`contactElementStrings[5]` contains an empty string.
`Integer.parseInt(contactElementStrings[5])` is throwing `NumberFormatException` because an empty string cannot be parsed to an `int`.

Add a check to see whether `contactElementStrings[5]` can be parsed to an `int`.

```java
int zipcode;
if (contactElementStrings.length > 6) {
    if (contactElementStrings[5] != null && !contactElementStrings[5].isEmpty()) {
        zipcode = Integer.parseInt(contactElementStrings[5]); 
    }
    else {
        zipcode = 0;
    }
}
```

### EDIT

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328528/read-file-into-string-by-separating-words-by-tab/67328619#comment119008442_67328619), it appears that there are lines that don't contain all the fields that you expect. Hence you also need to check whether the split line contains all the expected parts. I have edited the above code to also check whether the split line contains all the expected parts.

Comment: When adding the code I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.